Fields located in inactive tabs not being validated upon form submission
I want to use this validation:


function prueba(){
    console.log("hola")
}

$("#boton").off("click").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    prueba();
});
.tabset > input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -200vw;
}

.tabset .tab-panel {
    display: none;
}

.tabset > input:first-child:checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:first-child,
.tabset > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(2),
.tabset > input:nth-child(5):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(3),
.tabset > input:nth-child(7):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(4),
.tabset > input:nth-child(9):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(5),
.tabset > input:nth-child(11):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(6) {
    display: block;
}

.tabset > label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 15px 25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
}

    .tabset > label::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 10px;
        width: 22px;
        height: 4px;
        background: #8d8d8d;
    }

input:focus-visible + label {
    outline: 2px solid rgba(0,102,204,1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.tabset > label:hover,
.tabset > input:focus + label,
.tabset > input:checked + label {
    color: #06c;
}

    .tabset > label:hover::after,
    .tabset > input:focus + label::after,
    .tabset > input:checked + label::after {
        background: #06c;
    }

.tabset > input:checked + label {
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tab-panel {
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<form>
        <div class="tabset">

            <!-- Tab 1 -->
            <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab_datospersonales" aria-controls="datos_personales" checked>
            <label for="tab_datospersonales">Datos Personales</label>
            <!-- Tab 2 -->
            <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab_datostrabajador" aria-controls="datos_trabajador">
            <label for="tab_datostrabajador">Datos del Trabajador</label>

            <div class="tab-panels">

                    <section id="datos_personales" class="tab-panel">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br><br>
                        
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
                    </section>

                    <section id="datos_trabajador" class="tab-panel">
                        <label for="nombre">Cargo:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br><br>
                        
                        <label for="nombre">Area:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br><br>
            
                        <button id="boton" type="submit"> Actualizar</button>
                    </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="function.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



I'm facing an issue with form validation in a tabbed interface. I'm using regular tabs with radio buttons to switch between them. However, upon submitting the form, it fails to validate fields located in inactive tabs.
My aim is to have the form validate all fields, regardless of their visibility within the tabs. This ensures that all required fields are correctly filled out before the form is submitted, even if they are not currently visible to the user.
Instead of displaying validation for fields in inactive tabs, I encounter an error message in the console stating that the field is not focusable.
I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that all fields are validated, regardless of their visibility within the tabs, and how to appropriately display validation errors.

You'll need to post your form validation JS code. Not just your HTML. Keep in mind though that client side validation is a convenience service for your visitors. You can't rely on it for security. That must be done server side.

@icecub It is just the validation of jquery, in js I do not have validation, only an event that when everything is completed makes the registration.
For validation it is only necessary that they be inside a form and have a submit type button, this works correctly for me in another CRUD that does not have tabs

jQuery is JS. And unless you show us the code, we can't help you solve the problem. A car mechanic won't be able to tell you why your car won't start without showing them your car either.

@icecub only have this:
$("form").off("submit").one("submit", function (event) {         event.preventDefault();         guardarNewTrabajador();     });

There's a typo on that code. It should be $("form").off("submit").on("submit Not .one

@icecub You're right, I forgot to change it in this CRUD, but that doesn't influence my problem.
console says: An invalid form control with name=''" is not focusable.
This happens because the input is not in the tab that I am viewing

If that wasn't the problem, you'll have to edit your question and post the relevant JS code. The code you just commented is calling a function called guardarNewTrabajador(). That function is most likely responsible for handling your form validation. To see what's going on, you should post the code of it.

@icecub Update my question with an example where the error appears in the console

When you are using the build-in form validation (which you should), the browser will set focus to the invalid form field. When the form field is hidden, it is not possible to focus the element (therefore the error). In your case there can be more invalid form fields in more tabs, so I guess you will often be in a situation where you get the error that you describe.
The following example have two event listeners, one for the invalid event and the other for the input event. If a form field is invalid the call back function will be called. This happens when the user clicks the submit button -- so, any form field that is invalid will call this function one after the other. I the function I add the invalid class name to both form field and the parent section element (they get a red background color). I also change the tab by setting the radio button of the current tab to checked. This kind of works, but you always end on the last tab with an invalid form field.
The opposite happens when the user starts to type in a form field the input event call back function will be called, and if the form field is valid the invalid class name will be removed, and the same for the tab if all are valid.
I think this is as close as it gets.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  // set invalid class for the element
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
  // find the id of the section
  let id = e.target.closest('section').id;
  // change tab to the current tab
  e.target.form.querySelector(`input#tab_${id}`).checked = true;
  // set invalid class for the tab label
  e.target.form.querySelector(`label[for="tab_${id}"]`).classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    // remove the class invalid if valid
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
    // find the current section
    let section = e.target.closest('section');
    if (section) {
      // find fields in the current section that are invalid
      let stillInvalid = [...section.querySelectorAll('[required]')]
                           .find(elm => !elm.validity.valid);
      if (!stillInvalid) {
        // remove the class invalid if there are no invalid
        e.target.form.querySelector(`label[for="tab_${section.id}"]`).classList.remove('invalid');
      }
    }
  }
});
section {
  display: none;
}

input[name="tabset"]:checked+section {
  display: block;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

label {
  order: 1;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: black black white black;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: .1em;
  margin: 0 .1em;
  z-index: 100;
}

section {
  order: 2;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
<form name="form01">
  <!-- Tab 1 -->
  <label for="tab_datospersonales">Datos Personales</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab_datospersonales" aria-controls="datos_personales" checked hidden>
  <!-- datos_personales -->
  <section id="datospersonales" class="tab-panel">
    <!--mbre-->
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Nombre 1</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_trabajador_nombre" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ingrese su primer nombre">
    </div>

    <!-- Apellido P-->
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Apellido P.</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_trabajador_apellido_p" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ingrese su primer apellido">
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Tab 2 -->
  <label for="tab_datostrabajador">Datos del Trabajador</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab_datostrabajador" aria-controls="datos_trabajador" hidden>
  <!-- datos_Trabajador -->
  <section id="datostrabajador" class="tab-panel">

    <!-- trabajador_cargo -->
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Cargo/Responsabilidad</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_trabajador_cargo" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="40" placeholder="Ingrese su Cargo/Responsabilidad">
    </div>

    <!-- trabajador_categoria -->
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Categoría</span>
      <select class="form-control custom-select" id="input_trabajador_categoria" required>
        <option value="">seleccione...</option>
        <option value="I">Trabajador Interno</option>
        <option value="E">Trabajador Externo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button id="btnGuardarNewTrabajador" type="submit">Guardar Trabajador</button>
  </section>
</form>




Update my question with an example where the error appears in the console

@JorgeMantilla I updated my answer. I hope that it makes sense. Please ask if you have any questions.

Yes I was planning to do it, but I want to use the default validation, I pasted a photo of the validation that I want to use in the question

@JorgeMantilla I changed my answer more or less completely. Now, it is closer to what you are after.
